# VirtualBox MacOS Mojave Stuck on Shell script screen

Tags: xcode, virtualbox, macos-mojave

I am running a windows 10 and I have downloaded virtualbox, my macos Mojave file. Now I am stuck on this screen:
[image]

I have tried follow the instructions from: https://superuser.com/questions/1235970/stuck-on-uefi-interactive-shell-with-mac-os-x-high-sierra-vm/1351435

but now I get this error:
[image]

I was also following along this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hENCR6nEw&t=321s
and am stuck at 6:59.

Please help!!
I am trying to do all this so I can use xCode on my windows.

Comment: How did you managed to solve this? Am currently having the same issue

Comment: I just pay for Macincloud now